# How can I make type backgrounds in p5.js transparent?

Tags: javascript, p5.js, typography

Im having trouble making the background of the letter "A" transparent. you can see the letter "C" doesnt have this issue.

here an image displaying this.

[image]

here is my code: (ignore the portuguese)

```
let f;
function preload() {
  f = loadFont('assets/Inter-Bold.ttf')
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight, WEBGL); // criando o canvas 3D
  fontsize = 800;
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER)
  textFont(f)
  textSize(fontsize);
}

function draw() {
  background(255); // cor de fundo cinza claro
  rotateY(mouseX * 0.01); // rotação ao redor do eixo Y (opcional)
  
  // Primeiro plano 3D centralizado na página
  push(); // salvar a matriz de transformação atual
  translate(0, 0, 0);
  background(0,0);
  fill(0)
  text("A", 0, 0)
  
  // plane(500); // desenhar um plano de tamanho 300x300
  pop(); // restaurar a matriz de transformação anterior

  
  //------Segundo plano 3D cruzando o primeiro plano em 90 graus-------
  
  push(); // salvar a matriz de transformação atual
  translate(0, 0, 0); // mover para a direita e para cima
  rotateY(PI / 2); // rotacionar 90 graus em torno do eixo Y
  fill(0)
```

I dont know how to move on, Im an amateur to this also.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I think the WEBGL tag is actually important here. I'm fairly certain this behavior is specific to WEBGL because of the way it draws text.

Comment: @PaulWheeler I don't think the contributor is using p5.js, but not native WebGL. Even if WebGL is used under the hood, this is not a question about WebGL. This is a question of how to do it with p5.js. According to your opinion almost all p5.js, three.js, pixi.js, etc. questions should also get the tag WebGL.

Comment: @Rabbid76 gotcha, good point, maybe mention of WEBGL should be in the title or body of the question but without the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is the way p5.js draws text and how depth testing and blending works.

The way p5.js draws text is that it draws a single square (pair of triangles for each glyph<sup>*</sup> in the string). A GLSL shader is then used to actually render the glyph onto that set of triangles. This is as opposed to converting the vector curves of the font into individual triangles.

This combined with an issue with the GLSL shader p5.js uses to draw text causes **the bounding box** for a letter that has already been drawn to always cover up and hide any potion of a letter that is *later* drawn **behind it**. Here is the deal. In 3d graphics triangles are drawn one at a time, and as each one is drawn each screen pixel that it maps to (this is called a fragment) is assigned a color and a depth. When each fragment is drawn, its color is blended with whatever was already there based on its transparency. However, the **depth** of what is already there is also considered, and after blending all transparency information is lost, so if what is already there is closer to the camera than what is subsequently being draw then the fragment of the subsequent triangle is basically ignored (regardless of the transparency of the previously draw triangle).

There are basically two solutions to this: 1) make sure you don't have any intersecting triangles (if two triangles intersect, you must cut them up into multiple non-intersecting triangles), and then draw them back to front, or 2) have your fragment shader "discard" fragments who's opacity is below some threshold. The former is much more computationally expensive and difficult to implement, and the latter can result in some minor artifacts around anti-aliased edges (because you might blend a 50% opaque pixel with it's background and discard a 49% opaque pixel you'll wind up with some bleed through of the background right on the edge were a subsequently drawn letter is behind a previously drawn one).

Unfortunately there isn't a good way to patch the p5.js behavior in this case.

Here is a functional example of the problem:

```js
let roboto;

function preload() {
  roboto = loadFont("https://www.paulwheeler.us/files/Roboto.ttf");
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 300, WEBGL);
  angleMode(DEGREES);
  noLoop();
}

function draw() {
  background(200, 255, 200);
  noStroke();
  fill(0);
  textFont(roboto);
  textSize(220);
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  translate(0, -20, 0);
  push();
  rotateY(45);
  text('A', 0, 0);
  pop();
  rotateY(-45);
  fill(255, 0, 0);
  text('X', 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

<sup>*</sup> You can think of "glyph" as sort of like a letter, but sometimes what we think of as letters are actually multiple overlapping glyphs like O̊ is actually an O followed by a "COMBINING RING ABOVE").

### UPDATE: I did come up with a very hacky solution to make this work

There's a lot of code here, but the crux of it is we want to add the following to the end of the built in text fragment shader:

```c
  if (gl_FragColor.a < 0.5) {
    discard;
  }
```

This change is applied by patching the internal `_getFontShader` function on the WebGLRenderer. This is not a supported thing and will probably break in future versions.

```js
let roboto;

function preload() {
  roboto = loadFont("https://www.paulwheeler.us/files/Roboto.ttf");
}

function setup() {
  let renderer = createCanvas(400, 400, WEBGL);
  renderer._getFontShader = function() {
    if (!this._defaultFontShader) {
      this.GL.getExtension('OES_standard_derivatives');
      this._defaultFontShader = new p5.Shader(
        this,
        textVertGLSL,
        textFragGLSL
      );
    }
    return this._defaultFontShader;
  };
  
  angleMode(DEGREES);
  noLoop();
}

function draw() {
  background(200, 255, 200);
  noStroke();
  fill(0);
  textFont(roboto);
  textSize(120);
  textAlign(CENTER);
  push();
  rotateY(45);
  text('A', 0, 0);
  pop();
  rotateY(-45);
  fill(255, 0, 0);
  text('B', 0, 0);
}

let textVertGLSL = `precision mediump float;

attribute vec3 aPosition;
attribute vec2 aTexCoord;
uniform mat4 uModelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 uProjectionMatrix;

uniform vec4 uGlyphRect;
uniform float uGlyphOffset;

varying vec2 vTexCoord;
varying float w;

void main() {
  vec4 positionVec4 = vec4(aPosition, 1.0);

  // scale by the size of the glyph's rectangle
  positionVec4.xy *= uGlyphRect.zw - uGlyphRect.xy;

  // Expand glyph bounding boxes by 1px on each side to give a bit of room
  // for antialiasing
  vec2 pixelScale = vec2(
    1. / uModelViewMatrix[0][0],
    1. / uModelViewMatrix[1][1]
  );
  vec2 offset = pixelScale * normalize(aTexCoord - vec2(0.5, 0.5)) * vec2(1., -1.);
  vec2 textureOffset = offset * (1. / vec2(
    uGlyphRect.z - uGlyphRect.x,
    uGlyphRect.w - uGlyphRect.y
  ));

  // move to the corner of the glyph
  positionVec4.xy += uGlyphRect.xy;

  // move to the letter's line offset
  positionVec4.x += uGlyphOffset;

  positionVec4.xy += offset;
  
  gl_Position = uProjectionMatrix * uModelViewMatrix * positionVec4;
  vTexCoord = aTexCoord + textureOffset;
  w = gl_Position.w;
}`;

let textFragGLSL = `#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable
precision mediump float;

#if 0
  // simulate integer math using floats
    #define int float
    #define ivec2 vec2
    #define INT(x) float(x)

    int ifloor(float v) { return floor(v); }
    ivec2 ifloor(vec2 v) { return floor(v); }

#else
  // use native integer math
    precision highp int;
    #define INT(x) x

    int ifloor(float v) { return int(v); }
    int ifloor(int v) { return v; }
    ivec2 ifloor(vec2 v) { return ivec2(v); }

#endif

uniform sampler2D uSamplerStrokes;
uniform sampler2D uSamplerRowStrokes;
uniform sampler2D uSamplerRows;
uniform sampler2D uSamplerColStrokes;
uniform sampler2D uSamplerCols;

uniform ivec2 uStrokeImageSize;
uniform ivec2 uCellsImageSize;
uniform ivec2 uGridImageSize;

uniform ivec2 uGridOffset;
uniform ivec2 uGridSize;
uniform vec4 uMaterialColor;

varying vec2 vTexCoord;

// some helper functions
int round(float v) { return ifloor(v + 0.5); }
ivec2 round(vec2 v) { return ifloor(v + 0.5); }
float saturate(float v) { return clamp(v, 0.0, 1.0); }
vec2 saturate(vec2 v) { return clamp(v, 0.0, 1.0); }

int mul(float v1, int v2) {
  return ifloor(v1 * float(v2));
}

ivec2 mul(vec2 v1, ivec2 v2) {
  return ifloor(v1 * vec2(v2) + 0.5);
}

// unpack a 16-bit integer from a float vec2
int getInt16(vec2 v) {
  ivec2 iv = round(v * 255.0);
  return iv.x * INT(128) + iv.y;
}

vec2 pixelScale;
vec2 coverage = vec2(0.0);
vec2 weight = vec2(0.5);
const float minDistance = 1.0/8192.0;
const float hardness = 1.05; // amount of antialias

// the maximum number of curves in a glyph
const int N = INT(250);

// retrieves an indexed pixel from a sampler
vec4 getTexel(sampler2D sampler, int pos, ivec2 size) {
  int width = size.x;
  int y = ifloor(pos / width);
  int x = pos - y * width;  // pos % width

  return texture2D(sampler, (vec2(x, y) + 0.5) / vec2(size));
}

void calulateCrossings(vec2 p0, vec2 p1, vec2 p2, out vec2 C1, out vec2 C2) {

  // get the coefficients of the quadratic in t
  vec2 a = p0 - p1 * 2.0 + p2;
  vec2 b = p0 - p1;
  vec2 c = p0 - vTexCoord;

  // found out which values of 't' it crosses the axes
  vec2 surd = sqrt(max(vec2(0.0), b * b - a * c));
  vec2 t1 = ((b - surd) / a).yx;
  vec2 t2 = ((b + surd) / a).yx;

  // approximate straight lines to avoid rounding errors
  if (abs(a.y) < 0.001)
    t1.x = t2.x = c.y / (2.0 * b.y);

  if (abs(a.x) < 0.001)
    t1.y = t2.y = c.x / (2.0 * b.x);

  // plug into quadratic formula to find the corrdinates of the crossings
  C1 = ((a * t1 - b * 2.0) * t1 + c) * pixelScale;
  C2 = ((a * t2 - b * 2.0) * t2 + c) * pixelScale;
}

void coverageX(vec2 p0, vec2 p1, vec2 p2) {

  vec2 C1, C2;
  calulateCrossings(p0, p1, p2, C1, C2);

  // determine on which side of the x-axis the points lie
  bool y0 = p0.y > vTexCoord.y;
  bool y1 = p1.y > vTexCoord.y;
  bool y2 = p2.y > vTexCoord.y;

  // could web be under the curve (after t1)?
  if (y1 ? !y2 : y0) {
    // add the coverage for t1
    coverage.x += saturate(C1.x + 0.5);
    // calculate the anti-aliasing for t1
    weight.x = min(weight.x, abs(C1.x));
  }

  // are we outside the curve (after t2)?
  if (y1 ? !y0 : y2) {
    // subtract the coverage for t2
    coverage.x -= saturate(C2.x + 0.5);
    // calculate the anti-aliasing for t2
    weight.x = min(weight.x, abs(C2.x));
  }
}

// this is essentially the same as coverageX, but with the axes swapped
void coverageY(vec2 p0, vec2 p1, vec2 p2) {

  vec2 C1, C2;
  calulateCrossings(p0, p1, p2, C1, C2);

  bool x0 = p0.x > vTexCoord.x;
  bool x1 = p1.x > vTexCoord.x;
  bool x2 = p2.x > vTexCoord.x;

  if (x1 ? !x2 : x0) {
    coverage.y -= saturate(C1.y + 0.5);
    weight.y = min(weight.y, abs(C1.y));
  }

  if (x1 ? !x0 : x2) {
    coverage.y += saturate(C2.y + 0.5);
    weight.y = min(weight.y, abs(C2.y));
  }
}

void main() {

  // calculate the pixel scale based on screen-coordinates
  pixelScale = hardness / fwidth(vTexCoord);

  // which grid cell is this pixel in?
  ivec2 gridCoord = ifloor(vTexCoord * vec2(uGridSize));

  // intersect curves in this row
  {
    // the index into the row info bitmap
    int rowIndex = gridCoord.y + uGridOffset.y;
    // fetch the info texel
    vec4 rowInfo = getTexel(uSamplerRows, rowIndex, uGridImageSize);
    // unpack the rowInfo
    int rowStrokeIndex = getInt16(rowInfo.xy);
    int rowStrokeCount = getInt16(rowInfo.zw);

    for (int iRowStroke = INT(0); iRowStroke < N; iRowStroke++) {
      if (iRowStroke >= rowStrokeCount)
        break;

      // each stroke is made up of 3 points: the start and control point
      // and the start of the next curve.
      // fetch the indices of this pair of strokes:
      vec4 strokeIndices = getTexel(uSamplerRowStrokes, rowStrokeIndex++, uCellsImageSize);

      // unpack the stroke index
      int strokePos = getInt16(strokeIndices.xy);

      // fetch the two strokes
      vec4 stroke0 = getTexel(uSamplerStrokes, strokePos + INT(0), uStrokeImageSize);
      vec4 stroke1 = getTexel(uSamplerStrokes, strokePos + INT(1), uStrokeImageSize);

      // calculate the coverage
      coverageX(stroke0.xy, stroke0.zw, stroke1.xy);
    }
  }

  // intersect curves in this column
  {
    int colIndex = gridCoord.x + uGridOffset.x;
    vec4 colInfo = getTexel(uSamplerCols, colIndex, uGridImageSize);
    int colStrokeIndex = getInt16(colInfo.xy);
    int colStrokeCount = getInt16(colInfo.zw);
    
    for (int iColStroke = INT(0); iColStroke < N; iColStroke++) {
      if (iColStroke >= colStrokeCount)
        break;

      vec4 strokeIndices = getTexel(uSamplerColStrokes, colStrokeIndex++, uCellsImageSize);

      int strokePos = getInt16(strokeIndices.xy);
      vec4 stroke0 = getTexel(uSamplerStrokes, strokePos + INT(0), uStrokeImageSize);
      vec4 stroke1 = getTexel(uSamplerStrokes, strokePos + INT(1), uStrokeImageSize);
      coverageY(stroke0.xy, stroke0.zw, stroke1.xy);
    }
  }

  weight = saturate(1.0 - weight * 2.0);
  float distance = max(weight.x + weight.y, minDistance); // manhattan approx.
  float antialias = abs(dot(coverage, weight) / distance);
  float cover = min(abs(coverage.x), abs(coverage.y));
  gl_FragColor = vec4(uMaterialColor.rgb, 1.) * uMaterialColor.a;
  gl_FragColor *= saturate(max(antialias, cover));
  if (gl_FragColor.a < 0.5) {
    discard;
  }
}`;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

If you look really closely you can see the artifact I was talking about where some of the background bleeds in along the edges where the A drawn first is in front of the B drawn second.

[image: zoomed in screenshot of red B drawn after black A where A is in the foreground]

Comment: thank you for the explanation, I learned something today! I appreciate your answer.